# Change my Gmail sender address from firstname.lastname to firstnamelastname

Tags: gmail, username

When I created my Gmail account, I used `firstname.lastname` as my username.
But now I would prefer to use `firstnamelastname` (without the dot in between) for everything - so it's the very same username according to Gmail's own rules.

I know that this doesn't make any difference for receiving mails (I know that mails to `fi.RstnAm.elAs.tnaMe` would be delivered to me as well)

How do I change the sender/"from" address in Gmail?

When I send mails, the sender displayed is always `firstname.lastname`. I tried to [set up `firstnamelastname` as a sender in Gmail](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370), but Gmail doesn't let me.

The error message is:

> You can't send mails from firstnamelastname@gmail.com.

Setting up different senders works perfectly with addresses from other domains (I have set up a few successfully), but apparently Gmail doesn't allow to set up different "spellings" of the same Gmail username as senders.

Any idea if this is possible at all?

Comment: The [FAQ](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8158) suggests changing the e-mailadress, not adding a new send-from address.

Comment: Yes, but only if you want a completely different username. I'm fine with just "changing the dots". Greg's answer works for me though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Gmail go to Options (cog) → Settings → Accounts and Import

Under "Send mail as:" click on "Add another email address you own".

A popup will come out and under Email address, enter your "new" email address firstnamelastname@gmail.com and click next step.

This should close the window and now you should be able to send emails from your "modified" email address.

I've just tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: As I already said in my question - I tried this, and it doesn't work ("You can't send mails from firstnamelastname@gmail.com.").

Comment: Damn, you're right! It **does** work! The reason why it didn't work first was a different one than I first expected: I'm in Germany and here, Gmail is called Google Mail because of copyright issues (the name Gmail was already trademarked). So my real address is actually firstname.lastname@ **googlemail.com**, not ...@ **gmail.com**. For receiving mails, ...@gmail.com works as well, but apparently you can't use it as a sender. I got the error message when I tried to set firstnamelastname@gmail.com under "Send mail from another address". It works when I try firstnamelastname@googlemail.com.

Comment: Worth noting that right now this doesn't work on the Gmail iOS client. You can select `firstnamelastname@gmail.com` as the email address to send from and it looks like it will go from that address. However once you've sent the email, you can go back to it and see that it actually went from your login address (`firstname.lastname@gmail.com`). I don't know how long it has been broken like that.

Comment: @Richard This is broken on the web app also.