# Why does Gmail force a dot in my email address?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Google insists that [dots don't matter in an email address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en).

However:

- If I attempt to log in with `firstnamelastname@gmail.com` then it tells me I'm logged in as `firstname.lastname@gmail.com`.
- I am unable to send an email as `firstnamelastname@gmail.com`, it always comes from `firstname.lastname@gmail.com`.
- If I go into [myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com) then I'm told my Google Account email is `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` and that this cannot be changed.

If dots really don't matter, why do they appear to matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the dots *don't* matter in an email address, but they *do* matter in your login name, which is what your Gmail account name is.

So, your account is `firstname.lastname`. (Actually, it's `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` because you can create a login with a non-Gmail email address.)

You can receive mail sent to `firstname.lastname@gmail.com`, `firstnamelastname@gmail.com`, `first.namelast.name@gmail.com`, etc.

But when you log in you need that dot in the right place.

As for sending without the dot, you can do that too, but you have to set up an alias in your Gmail settings. (See: [Change my Gmail sender address from firstname.lastname to firstnamelastname](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17975/354))